# Changing email to just a simple first name

Tags: visual-studio-code

My question is how I change what is shown to others in terms of ID in VS Code, I see my email as my ID and I would like it to simply show my first name as my ID when working on a project with a group etc.

I am unable to find a direct answer to this question

Comment: welcome! what id are you talking about?

Comment: Basically the ID that is shown under account in VS Code. I would like simply my first name for example and not a full email as it currently is showing etc.

Comment: Where specifically?